# R get time after dark

Tags: r

So I have data frame with times, like 2016-11-01 23:21:15
I formated the columns with
 `as.POSIXct(month$stopdate, format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S%p")`

so no lubridate, although I don't even know what that is

The data frame has the entire month in it, so 11/1,11/2,11/3 and so on.

I would like to get a subset of all the times after dark, say 6pm(18:00:00) for each day

so a subset of all times after 6pm for 11/1, 11/2,11/3

example data

```
11/1/2016 0:00
11/1/2016 0:54
11/1/2016 2:25
11/1/2016 2:57
11/1/2016 7:01
11/1/2016 7:32
11/1/2016 7:54
11/1/2016 8:08
11/2/2016 1:55
11/2/2016 8:56
11/2/2016 18:56
11/3/2016 7:03
11/3/2016 15:10
11/3/2016 15:12
```

I would like to get

```
11/1/2016 7:01
11/1/2016 7:32
11/1/2016 7:54
11/1/2016 8:08
11/2/2016 8:56
11/2/2016 18:56
11/3/2016 7:03
11/3/2016 15:10
11/3/2016 15:12
```

Thank you

Comment: Most of the times given in your desired output are not after 18:00.  Could you please clarify?

Comment: sorry about that, i meant after 6 am for each day